# Less files are not loading on live server?

Tags: javascript, css, less

Okay my problem is that the less files are not working on the live server. I have made double sure that they are there and that the paths are correct, but it just is not working.

This does however work fine on the localhost.

My script is as follows

```
<link href="fonts/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- CSS files for plugins -->
<link href="stylesheets/pace.preloader.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="stylesheets/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="stylesheets/parallax.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="stylesheets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="stylesheets/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="stylesheets/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" > 
<link href="stylesheets/jquery.tweet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="stylesheets/foliohover.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="stylesheets/fancymenu.css"  rel="stylesheet">
<link href="stylesheets/intro.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="less/color.less" />

<!-- Main Template Styles -->
<link href="stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Main Template Responsive Styles -->
<link href="stylesheets/main-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Main Template Retina Optimizaton Rules -->
<link href="stylesheets/main-retina.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- LESS stylesheet for managing color presets -->
<!-- LESS JS engine-->
<script src="less/less-1.5.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
```

If you open inspect element you will see the 404 errors for the less files

View the site live here: www.codethis.co.za

Please any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Why are you referencing the less files and not the css files ?

Comment: @OmriAharon sorry I should have pointed out that this is from a template. I have never worked with less before so I really am not sure why this happening.

Comment: the less files are creating css files, and you should be referencing the css file itself. (meaning. color.css and not color.less)

Comment: Firstly, this is not going to work. LESS is a preprocessor language that needs to be compiled into CSS (use a server side solution to do this or use CodeKit). Secondly, your IIS is not setup to serve LESS files, hence why you get the "The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration" error in the response from the server. Please see http://davidsonsousa.net/en/post/using-webconfig-to-make-your-aspnet-project-accept-css-less

Comment: Thanks you, this has sorted out my problem and it is now working? How do I give you a vote here buddy

Comment: For me it looks as simple as your web-server is just not configured to serve files with `less` extension (and/or its `/less` and btw. `/fonts` directories as a whole). Actually http://www.codethis.co.za/less/color.less says it pretty clear.